Is sequence $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left( k+\frac{1}{k}\right)$ bounded? If so, does $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sin k-\sin\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)$ converge?
It is well-known that the sequence $a_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin k$ is bounded.
I want to see if $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sin k - \sin\left( k+\frac{1}{k} \right)\ $ converges. The reason this is interesting is because $\sin k - \sin\left( k+\frac{1}{k} \right)\ $ is close to $\pm \frac{1}{k}$ quite often (for about half of the integers $k$).
But then I realised that I can't even prove that $b_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left( k+\frac{1}{k} \right) $ is bounded, because the methods for proving that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin k$ is bounded don't work for $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left( k+\frac{1}{k} \right). $ Let's see why:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left( k+\frac{1}{k} \right) $$
$$ = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \left(e^{i\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k^2} \right)}\right)^k-\sum_{k=1}^n \left(e^{-i\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k^2} \right)}\right)^k}{2i} $$
But now we cannot say that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n z^k=z\frac{1-z^n}{1-z}\ $ where $\ z = e^{i\left( 1 + \frac{1}{k^2} \right)},$ because here $z$ is non-constant.
So my questions are:

Is my above analysis correct?

Is it known if $b_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin\left( k+\frac{1}{k} \right) $ is bounded?

Does $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sin k - \sin\left( k+\frac{1}{k} \right)\ $ converge?



Maybe Abel summation was not such a good idea, the simplest would maybe be $\sin(k) \sim \sin(k+1/k)$ so both series have the same behavior

It is not obvious to me that $\sin k \sim \sin(k+1/k).$

I would say it's tricky since $\sin(k)$ often goes near zero indeed, This was just an idea. Also the formula $\sin(a+b)$ may be simple but can work alongside with some Abel summation

Yes, and when $\sin k = c,\ c$ close to $0,\quad \sin(k+1/k)$ is either near $c+1/k$ or $c-1/k.$

If $\sin k \sim \sin(k+1/k)$ means $\lim_{k\to+\infty} \sin k / \sin(k+1/k) = 1$, then it is true. (It gives $|\sin(k+1/k)| < (1+\varepsilon) |\sin k|$ for sufficiently large $k$.)

@Y.D.X. Can you prove that $\forall\ \varepsilon>0,\quad \exists\ K\ $ s.t. $ \vert \sin(k+1/k)\vert < (1+\varepsilon) \vert \sin k \vert\ \quad \forall\ k\geq K?$ This is far from obvious to me. Basically saying that $k+1/k$ is not close to $\pi\mathbb{N}.$

Sorry, I realize my fault…

First of all, your analysis seems correct: you can't use the same exact methods.
If you study $u_k = \sin(k) - \sin\left(k + 1/k\right)$, you easily get $u_k \sim -\sin'(k)/k = -\cos(k)/k$.
You could also have used (if you did not want to deal with derivative):
$$\begin{align*}\sin k - \sin\left(k + 1/k\right) &= \sin k - \sin k \cos \frac{1}{k} - \cos k \sin \frac{1}{k} \\
&= \sin k \left(1-\cos\frac{1}{k}\right) - \cos k \sin \frac{1}{k}\\
&\sim \frac{\sin k}{2k^2} - \frac{\cos k}{k} \sim - \frac{\cos k}{k}
\end{align*}$$

Let us study $v_k = \frac{\cos k }{k}$. We put $S_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \cos k$.
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^N v_n &= \sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{\cos n }{n} = \sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{S_n - S_{n-1} }{n} = \sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{S_n}{n} - \sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{S_{n-1} }{n}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{S_n }{n} - \sum_{n=-1}^{N-1}  \frac{S_n}{n+1} = \frac{S_N}{N} - S_{-1}  + \sum_{n=0}^N  S_n \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
&= \frac{S_N}{N}- 0 +\sum_{n=0}^N  \frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}
\end{align*} $$
But since $S_n$ is bounded, this converges, hence $\sum u_k$ converges.

NB: this trick with the $S_n$ can also be done with $R_n$ (series of the rest) and is called Abel's summation. This is a discrete version of integration by parts.

Now obviously, this convergence plus the boundedness of $\sum \sin k$ implies the boundedness of $\sum \sin(k+1/k)$ since $\sin(k+1/k) = \sin k - u_k$.
Maybe you can try to show that if $\left(\sum_{k\leq n} a_k \right)_n$ is bounded and $\alpha>0$, then $\sum \frac{a_n}{n^\alpha}$ converges.

Yes, my bad, let me correct this (although the main thing is the $O(1/k^2)$)

Right so $\sum \sin k - \sin(k + 1/k) \approx \sum \frac{\sin k}{2k^2} - \frac{\cos k}{k}.$ Now $ \sum \frac{\sin k}{2k^2}$ converges by comparison with $ \sum \frac{1}{k^2}$ and absolute convergence implies convergence. And $\sum\frac{\cos k}{k}$ converges by Dirichlet's Test, or by your analysis in the previous paragraph.

I don't know about Dirichlet's test is it a summation by packs? Anyways I have shown it converges in my answer.

Dirichlet's test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test with $b_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos k$ (which is bounded), and $a_n: = 1/n.$

Okay, this is a weaker version of the exercise I suggested below (that can be solved using Abel summation).

Hmm...I think your exercise is a specific instance of Dirichlet's test. In wikipedia's Dirichlet's test, replace $b_n$ with your $a_n$ and replace $a_n$  with your $\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}.$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
